# CURL делает 2 запроса

Tags: php, curl

Суть проблемы, через curl отправляю 1 запрос, а на стороне скрипта который принимает запрос, 2 запроса, т.е. вместо одного curl отправляет 2 запроса.

Подскажите как решить проблему.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mysite.com/upload.php?user_id=134');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['file' => new CURLFile($file)]);
$res_api = curl_exec($curl);
curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: у вас 2 строчки отправляют curl_exec($curl); u  $res_api = curl_exec($curl); удалить одну

Comment: Спасибо, ступил не увидел...

Answer (score 1):

Вы два раза вызываете функцию **curl_exec**. 
Просто уберите последнюю строчку